# Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, close-reasons, data-dump

A couple of previous questions ([How to find the actual close reason for a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279534/how-to-find-the-actual-close-reason-for-a-question) and [How to determine why a question was closed from the data dump/data explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202025/how-to-determine-why-a-question-was-closed-from-the-data-dump-data-explorer)) document the fact that it is currently impossible to find out the precise individual closure-as-off-topic reason used on any given question, i.e. the ones indexed in the `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes` table, via the Data Explorer.

This is a bit weird, because it is very public data, and it would be very useful both for collating statistics and to enable easier and more in-depth auditing of how each closure reason is used in practice. Moreover, it should be easy to implement: the information obviously exists already, and all it takes is adding a column `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId` to that table linking back to the existing `Types` table.

As mentioned in the linked questions,

> Is this a bug or missing feature? I can't tell

but it doesn't really matter: either way, please implement this!

Comment: Related: [Break “off topic” close reasons into specific reasons in Tools rather than grouping them in one bucket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279235/break-off-topic-close-reasons-into-specific-reasons-in-tools-rather-than-group).

Comment: I spent some time in Data Explorer trying to dig this information until I noticed this post. Yes, we want this! It will help to do some data mining on close reasons.

Comment: Just wanted to ask the same. It would be so useful.

Comment: Adding this would resolve this [tag:support] request: [_How can we write a query in data.stackexchange to find the CloseAsOffTopicReasonType for a closed question?_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/255880/997587)