# How would one know which sub-reason of "off-topic" was a question previously closed for (now reopened)?

Tags: support, close-reasons, revisions-list

Past close & reopen events are visible in a post's revision and timeline, and duplicate records are also available publicly on the same page. However, I can't find a way to determine which sub-reason of "off-topic" (e.g. on MSE *only one site* or *no longer reproducible*) was previously applied to a question that's been reopened since. How would one find that information?

Comment: related: [After question is closed expose close votes distinguished by reason in the timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284886/165773)

Comment: It's not possible via the API or [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750/295232).